# using a single transaction scope to have db queries across 2 different db servers

Tags: msdtc

I am using transaction scope. I want to have a transaction scope for 2 queries that are run in different database servers. One query runs on one server and the other one runs in a different server.

However a single query will have its own transaction scope as it is to work with multiple tables.

I am getting the following excpetion

```
The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On remote hosts (DB servers in that case):

- From Control Panel, open Administrative Tools, and then open Component Services.
- Expand Component Services, right-click My Computer, and then select Properties.
- Click the MSDTC tab, and then click Security Configuration.
- Tick anything under "network DTC access".

Check that the firewalls don't block MSDTC as well on clients and servers.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the first answer MSDTC must be enabled on both client and server machines. However, in addition there may be some extra configuration required especially if firewalls are involved. The following link: [MSDTC Troubleshooting](http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/msdtc-troubleshooting) describes many of the possible errors that may occur, how to fix them and some useful tools for debugging such as [DTCTester](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293799) and [DTCPing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918331).

Other troubleshooting links include:

- [Troubleshooting MSDTC issues with DTCPing tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2008/11/12/troubleshooting-msdtc-issues-with-the-dtcping-tool.aspx)
- [Troubleshooting Problems with MSDTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the tools suggestions and its related tutorial links, really helpful for future references.